# How do I add selected UVs to a list in order to access them later?

Tags: python, uv

I'm trying to create a UV selection set of faces, edges, or verts depending on what I have selected so that after I run an operation like, `bpy.ops.uv.select_linked()` or `bpy.ops.object.texel_density_check()` I can revert to the selection I had before.

Comment: Deleting your previous, very similar question demotivates me from writing an answer... Basically, you could save the UV data to a list, using e.g. list comprehension, then restore that data using `mesh.uv_layers['name'].data.foreach_set(saved_list)`.

Comment: I'm not trying to commit a faux pas here. I should've edited the first question in hindsight. I just realized this might be a more specific way to ask it and in the whirlwind of trying to figure out this completely new world I stepped on some toes. Apologies.

Thank you for your answer. I appreciate your time.